# String array won't add string in a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I am tryiing to make a hangman game in Java, but I am having problems initializing a variable `lStorage`. I have added `String[] lStorage`,but still not initializing.

```
switch(difficulty){
    case 0:
        String[] easywords= new String[]{"integer","project","octopus"};
        int wrong = 12;
        String[] lStorage;
        String easyrnd = (easywords[new Random().nextInt(easywords.length)]);
        System.out.println("The word has " + easyrnd.length() + " Letters");
        while(wrong>=0){
        System.out.println("\n guess a letter");
        String letterguess = consolereader.nextLine();

        if(easyrnd.contains(letterguess)){
            System.out.println("correct " + letterguess + " is the " + "...number" + "Letter"); //need to put in number of letter
            for(int i=12;i>0;i--){
                lStorage[i]=letterguess;
            }
```

Comment: *Which* variable? Which line is failing? I can't see any initialization of the `lStorage` variable, mind you. Where do *you* think you assign it a value?

Comment: Initializing should be something like : String[] lStorage = new String[12];

Comment: `String[] lStorage;` *" it says that the variable hasn't been initialised, even though it has"* The variable has been declared, **not** initialized.

Comment: You never initialize and define a size for your lStorage array.

Comment: `String[] lStorage;` is inside the `switch` statement, unless you explicitly declare it, it is not initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array actually *hasn't* been initialized. What you've done is *declared* it. Try something like this:

```
String[] lStorage = new String[size];
```

If this array has to be dynamically sized, I would suggest using a `java.util.List` or another collection class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `String` array

Try to change this line

```
String[] lStorage;
```

to this one

```
String[] lStorage = new String[12];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays are objects (like in C# and probably many other object oriented languages). So, you must create/initialize them using the `new` keyword.